# Nagios not resolving macros in email alert

Tags: amazon-web-services, monitoring, nagios

I'm sending Nagios Alerts using a email script.
the command is

```
define command{
      command_name  notify-host-by-email
      command_line  bash /etc/nagios/servers/email.sh /usr/local/aws/bin/aws from_email@abc.com to_email@abc.com 'NAGIOS Alert : $NOTIFICATIONTYPE$' 'Notification Type: $NOTIFICATIONTYPE$<br />Host: $HOSTNAME$<br />State: $HOSTSTATE$<br />Address: $HOSTADDRESS$<br />Info:$HOSTOUTPUT$<br />Date/Time: $LONGDATETIME$\n<br />'
      }
```

And my email script file says :

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "____Sending Mail___ "
echo "To : "$2
echo "From: "$3
echo "Subject: "$4
echo "Message: "$5

source /etc/environment
echo '{"Subject":{"Data":"'"$4"'","Charset":"UTF-8"},"Body":{"Html":{"Data":"'"$5"'","Charset":"UTF-8"}}}' > /etc/nagios/servers/template.json
$1 ses send-email --region "us-west-2" --destination ToAddresses=$2 --from $3 --message file:///etc/nagios/servers/template.json
```

I'm sending mail using AWS Email service CLI

But the mail I receive says :

```
Notification Type: $NOTIFICATIONTYPE$
Host: $HOSTNAME$
State: $HOSTSTATE$
Address: $HOSTADDRESS$
Info:$HOSTOUTPUT$
Date/Time: $LONGDATETIME$
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it...

Here's the command :

```
define command{
      command_name  notify-host-by-email
      command_line  bash /etc/nagios/servers/email.sh /usr/local/aws/bin/aws from_email@abc.com to_email@abc.com "NAGIOS $NOTIFICATIONTYPE$ Alert : $HOSTNAME$" "Notification Type: '$NOTIFICATIONTYPE$'<br />Host: '$HOSTNAME$'<br />State: '$HOSTSTATE$'<br />Address: '$HOSTADDRESS$'<br />Info:'$HOSTOUTPUT$'<br />Date/Time: '$LONGDATETIME$'\n<br />"
      }
```

Another issue had cropped up, it was sending same mail notification repeatedly, I suppose it was because multiple notifications were using same template.json. So here I'm creating a temp json and deleting it after mail is sent. Also added logging in syslog. It helped a lot.
email.sh :

```
#!/bin/bash

logger -i "____Sending Mail___ To : '$2'  From: '$3'"
logger -i " With Subject: '$4'"
logger -i " With Message: '$5'"
logger -i "User : '$USER'"
temp_file_name=$(cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9' | fold -w 32 | head -n 1)

source /etc/environment
touch /tmp/$temp_file_name.json |& logger

echo '{"Subject":{"Data":"'"$4"'","Charset":"UTF-8"},"Body":{"Html":{"Data":"'"$5"'","Charset":"UTF-8"}}}' > /tmp/$temp_file_name.json
$1 ses send-email --region "us-east-1" --destination ToAddresses=$2 --from $3 --message file:///tmp/$temp_file_name.json |& logger

rm  /tmp/$temp_file_name.json |& logger
```