# How to retrive Macros Value of a host from nagios core?

Tags: python, bash, alert, nagios, gammu

I have a `Nagios-core` server  for monitoring my network and I want to configure an alert via sms but the problem is the sms gateway is on another host,
my idea is to retrieve the `macro's` value of the hosts and send it to the sms gateway.

**Not:** The sms gateway used is `Gammu.`

I create a `command-line` on the `Nagios` server but it doesn't work  :

the command line contains a full path of the script `notify_BY-SMS.sh`

```
define command{
        command_name    notify-host-by-sms
        command_line    /usr/local/nagios/libexec/notify_BY-SMS.sh

        }
```

the script `notify_BY-SMS.sh` is described below:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

I try to retrieve the `$HOSTNAME$` `$HOSTSTATE$` Macros from Nagios and set it on a variable named `$message` :

```
message=$(/usr/bin/printf "%b" "Alert $HOSTNAME$ is $HOSTSTATE$")
```

retrieve the `$CONTACTPAGER$` macros and set it on a variable named `$contact` :

```
contact=$(/usr/bin/printf "%b" $CONTACTPAGER$)
```

connect to `MySQL` users remotely `centreon`  :

```
mysql -h 192.X.Y.Z -u centreon -D smsd --password=<PASSWORD>
```

and I try to insert the variable sets INTO the Gammu outbox table :

```
-e "INSERT INTO outbox (\`CreatorID\`, \`SenderID\`, \`DeliveryReport\`, \`MultiPart\`, \`InsertIntoDB\`, \`Text\`, \`DestinationNumber\`, \`RelativeValidity\`, \`Coding\`, \`UDH\`, \`Class\`, \`TextDecoded\`) VALUES ('Gammu 1.41.0', '2', 'default', 'FALSE', NOW(), '', '$contact', 255, 'Default_No_Compression', '', -1, '$message');"
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using nagios variables in your bash script. You need to use bash variables: $1, $2, $3, etc.

If you have something like:
command_line /usr/local/nagios/libexec/notify_BY-SMS.sh $HOSTNAME$ $HOSTSTATE$

Then in your bash script do something like:
message=$(/usr/bin/printf "%b" "Alert $1 is $2")

Refer to this question for a deep explanation:

[Nagios not resolving macros in email alert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37093032/nagios-not-resolving-macros-in-email-alert)